# SQL get all Data from one table connected with another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got an little DB with two tables `Weeks` and `Users`.

Every User is able to have a Week, so let's say he can have a Week but must not.

Every `Week` has a `WeekNr`. I want to do a table like that for an specific `WeekNr`, where all users are shown even those without a Week with that `WeekNr`:

```
-------------------------------------------+
| Users    |  KM Driven | Goal    | CarID  |
+----------+------------+------------------+
| Driver1  |     555    |  Spain  |   1    |
+----------+------------+------------------+
| Driver2  |       0    |     0   |   0    |
+----------+------------+------------------+
| Driver3  |     777    | Germany |   9    |
+----------+------------+------------------+
| Driver4  |     888    |   UK    |   86   |
+----------+------------+------------------+
```

If there is a `user` which have no `Week` for a `WeekNr` and I want all columns expected his name filled with `0`. See `Driver2` in table above for an example.

My query looks actually like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User 
INNER JOIN Week ON Week.UserId = User.UserID 
WHERE WeekNr = 22;
```

I totally understand why I'm only getting only the drivers with weeks for the specific `WeekNr`, but I have no clue how to solve the issue with filling the empty one with `0` and all of this in one query.

I hope my question got clear.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**EDIT:**

My table look like this

Users:

```
---------------------------------+
| User     |     PW     | UserID |
+----------+------------+--------+
| Driver1  |     ***    |   1    |
| Driver2  |     ***    |   2    |
| Driver3  |     ***    |   3    |
| Driver4  |     ***    |   4    |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

Weeks:

```
------------------------------------------------------+
| WeekNr   |  KM Driven | Goal    | WeekID |  UserID  |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
|    22    |     555    |  Spain  |   1    |     1    |
|    22    |       0    |   USA   |   2    |     3    |
|    22    |     777    | Germany |   3    |     4    |
|    23    |     888    |   UK    |   44   |     2    |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: If you need the weeks that dont have users try using right join... or left join inverting the tables in your select

Comment: @wdoering I need Users that don't have a week for a speciffic WeekNR also displayed when I'm searching for that speciffic WeekNr. In my Ecample like Driver2. He hasn't an entry for WeekNr 22 but he still displayed.

Comment: Would be easier if you could give us the data tables structures and some data to populate them ... basing on what you're showing it is not easy.

Comment: @Simone okay just a moment

Comment: @Simone see my edit. And tell me if you need more

Comment: @FelixGerber please check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to have correctly understood your question: your problem is in the INNER JOIN, you get only rows present in both the tables. Try with LEFT OUTER:

EDIT:
That should do the trick, given tha additional info :)

```
;WITH Drivers AS (SELECT u.[User], w.* 
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN  Weeks w On w.UserId = u.UserID 
WHERE WeekNr = 22) 
SELECT u.[User], ISNULL(d.[KM Driven], 0) [KM Driven] , ISNULL(d.Goal, 0) Goal --, * 
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN Drivers d ON u.UserID = d.UserID
```

Comment: Having the LEFT JOIN's right side table's conditions in the WHERE clause like that makes the LEFT JOIN execute as a regular inner join. Move to ON clause to get true LET JOIN behavior!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in the result of your query driver2 (the driver wtihout a week with weeknr 22 of my example) is still missing. Do you have any other idea why?

Comment: Would be easier if you could give us the data tables structures and some data to populate them ... basing on what you're showing it is not easy. Did you try jarlh suggestion?

Comment: @FelixGerber I've improved the answer to give correct result: LEFT OUTER JOIN & extended WHERE clause should make the magic

Answer (score 1):

Is there a typo in your question? I presume CarID is meant to be a column of Weeks. If so,

```
SELECT
    u.[User]
,   ISNULL(w.[KM Driven], 0) [KM Driven]
,   ISNULL(w.[Goal], '0') [Goal]
,   ISNULL(w.[CarID], 0) [CarID]
FROM dbo.[Users] u
    LEFT JOIN Weeks w ON u.UserID = w.UserID AND WeekNr = 22
```